# Finding Similar Birthday through structure data

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

Hey guys I am trying to get the number of people who have the same birthday but this solution isn't working.This program is showing 0.0% .Please help me ...!.

```
public double calculate(int size, int count) {
    int matches = 0;//initializing an integer variable
    boolean out = false;
    List<Integer> days=new ArrayList<Integer>();// creating arraylist name days  of type int
    for (int j = 0; j <count; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {// initializing for loop till less than size
            Random rand = new Random(); // creating an object of random function

            int Brday = rand.nextInt(364) + 0;//initializing the limit of randomc number chozen

            days.add(Brday); //adding values to arraylist
        }

        for (int l = 0; l < size; l++) {
            int temp = l;//assigning value of l to a variable
            for (int k = l + 1; k < size; k++) {
                if (days.get(k) == temp) {// check statement to check values are same

                    matches++;//incrementing variable
                    out = true;
                    mOut.print("Count does have same birthday" + matches);
                    break;

                } else {
                    mOut.print("does not have same birthday");

                }
            }
            if (out) {
                out = false;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    double prob = (double) matches / count;
    mOut.print("The probability for two students to share a birthday is " + prob*100 + ".");
    return prob;//returning double value of the function
}
```

Comment: @RC. The OP isn't using == with objects, he's using == with `Integer` and `int`, which results in auto-unboxing.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt You are right, my bad.

Comment: Can't you use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you get either 0 percent or 100 percent with your code. Try invoking it with `calculate(100, 100)` if you want to see.

There are two things that are wrong in this code. First, if you run the simulation more than once (`count` > 1) then you never clear the list of birthdays before the second iteration.

Your method should begin with:

```
public double calculate(int size, int count) {
    int matches = 0;
    boolean out = false;
    List<Integer> days;
    for (int j = 0; j <count; j++) {
        days = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Secondly, you're not comparing two birthdays but you're comparing a birthday to the index in the list.

This line:

```
int temp = l;//assigning value of l to a variable
```

Should read:

```
int temp = days.get(l); // Remember the birthday at index l
```

With those changes you'll get a much better result.

Comment: thank you so much for  such a good response.It is working now  but there is a problem it is taking  much time  for large values. it will be very nice of you if you suggest me a solution of this too....

Comment: @FarasatNiazi I take it that you find the answer useful. Can you upvote the answer? If you hover over upvote button you see in the tooltip that this means "this answer is useful"

Comment: please suggest me less time consuming solution and solution that can work on large values?